# python version check command works only in user mode and not root

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm new to Linux and Amazon AWS. I installed Python3.6 on Amazon Linux and when I run the command to check python version, the command works only for the normal user but it doesn't work for the root account. Why is that?

> ```
> [ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-209 /]$ python3.6 --version
> Python 3.6.6
> [ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-209 /]$ sudo su
> [root@ip-172-31-30-209 /]# python3.6 --version
> bash: python3.6: command not found
> [root@ip-172-31-30-209 /]#
> ```

Comment: On Linux, each user, including root, has their own independent PATH environment variable, which tells the OS in which directories to look for executables. There is lots of searchable advice on how to set this.

Answer (score 1):

check the owner of the python installation folder or add that ec2-user to root user group.

[Add User to sudo group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213958/can-i-add-myself-to-group-root)